# Blocking GTM after it is executed without refreshing the page

Tags: google-tag-manager

We have an app for cookie management and we can't seem to find a way to block/disable the GTM and its tags after it was initially executed/enabled without refreshing the page.

Basically, what we require is, if all of the cookie categories are initially enabled and therefore GTM is running initially, and after that, the visitor choose to change his cookie preferences and block all of the cookie categories, there is no way to block/disable the GTM(and his tags) without having to reset the page. The only workaround for that is to block the GTM script before it is loaded, but this requires a page reset.

We are looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you do not just want to stop tags from firing (which would be simple), but you basically want to "unload" the gtm file?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to disable GTM, or to be more precise, to break the GTM instance running on the page.

GTM requires a "dataLayer" variable to work, that is an array of objects that communicates values from the frontend to the javascript that is the actual "engine" of client-side GTM. The datalayer is an array of objects.

GTM overloads the "push" method of the datalayer array with a custom function that, amongst other things, scans for the "event" key in datalayer objects. When it finds the event key, it updates the internal state of the variables an executes all triggers that are connected to that specific event.

So if you break that function, by re-initializing the datalayer variable or by overloading the push method again e.g. with a function that returns a null value, you effectively cripple GTM to a point where it can no longer execute tags.

```
datalayer.push = function() { return null; }
```

This will not unload the file (unloading JS is not possible without a reload), it will not purge GTM from memory and will not remove anything that GTM has injected into the page up to this point. This is a bit of a hack, and the datalayer variable name is configurable, so you need to check first how the datalayer is actually called. But breaking the datalayer variable (actual implementation might need a bit more work, but that is the principle) will stop GTM effectively from interacting with the page in any meaningful manner.